# How do I use BigInteger in settings.settings?

Tags: c#, biginteger, settings.settings

I have setup a reference in my project to System.Numerics, but I cannot seem to get the ability to store BigInteger as a setting in settings.settings.

I have tried browsing and then selecting the System.Numerics, but this just takes away the dropdown arrow next to it and doesn't allow me to select anything.

Comment: Can you just store a string, and parse it during application of settings?

Comment: @BenVoigt I could... However I would really rather not. These values are going to be getting some heavy use, and I really don't want to have to be converting so frequently. It is an option, but if I can store BigInteger's instead that would be optimal. :)

Comment: I meant to convert once per run of your program, not every time you access the value.  Because app settings are stored in XML, you will have to pay the cost of parsing anyway.

Comment: I plan on changing these values very frequently - potentiolly under a second. I then plan on saving them back to not lose the values ~ every ten seconds.

Comment: You seem to think that "Settings" is a global storage for your program during runtime.  It isn't.  It provides persistence.  Use a `BigInteger` variable (not a setting) for the value used inside your program, and convert to/from string only when saving it to the settings file.